High accuracy image trace options for high detail raster images?
I regularly need to convert low quality, high resolution images into vectors and i have been using the Image Trace function to do so, While the results are decent so far, some details are lost or improperly traced. I'll provide an example of what i am trying to trace and its results as well as common issues i come across, the settings as well of course.
Image

Close up

Image trace result

Like i said the results arent bad, its pretty accurate on larger segments but close-together segments like this cause the image trace algorithm to overlap the paths.
I've tinkered around with the settings abit and these gave me the best results
Image trace settings

I'll also provide the file that i'm working on but i'd like to know if theres any better settings/method to do this.
Thanks

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The image is too low resolution for a good auto trace result. I'm afraid it's a case of garbage in, garbage out.  There's no magic fix. You would be better tracing it manually with the Pen Tool.  They're not massively complex.

I'm not certain you'll ever get a 100% solid tracing of that. it's certainly not what I would call "high detail". To me it's more like poor detail. But there are a couple things you can do to at least try and improve results.
The best solution is the manually trace the image. Shapes are simple and nothing is complex. Basic knowledge of the Pen Tool is all one would need. But, barring that....

Open raster image in Photoshop.
Duplicate layer, set the blend mode on duplicate to Multiply, merge down
Repeat once or twice - duplicate, multiply, merge down.
Choose Filter > Other > Minimum add a couple pixels, just 2 or 3.
Save this and open (or just drag and drop) into Illustrator
Bring up Image Trace and use Preset: Line Art as a starting point.
Play with the sliders to get something decent... (tick Ignore White in the advanced settings, but don't tick/untick anything else)


Expand...

Zoomed...

It's not perfect, by any means, but it's about the best you are going to get without manually tracing things.
By using the Line Art settings as a default expanding the trace will result in strokes and not filled shapes. The results are much easier to clean up and refine as strokes rather than filled shapes.
In many instances you do not want sliders all the way to the left or the right. You want to leave a little room to let the app determine the best path(s). By maxing out the sliders you ensure the app can't adjust paths for very minute variances (which is why you see every little pixel step in your results.)
